# prove perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that if $ab$ and $bc$ are perfect squares then $ac$ is a perfect square using theorem of arithmetic. I am not exactly sure how to prove this.
I know that a perfect square must have even powers of primes so set 
$a = p_1^{2k}$, $b = p_1^{2k}$ and $c= p_1^{2k}$ then $ac = p_1^{2k+2k}$ is this the correct approch to prove this ?

Many Thanks

Comment: Note that a isn't a perfect square but rather ab is.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [Tex](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).  It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: This is not true unless $b \ne 0$.  The proof depends in an essential way on being able to divide by $b$.

Comment: @JuanSebastianLozanoMuñoz: our edits got crossed, but I second your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the highest power of prime $p$ in $a,b,c$ be $A,B,C$ respectively.

As $ab$ is perfect square, $A+B$ is even

Similarly,   $B+C$ will be even $\implies (A+B)+ (B+C)$ will be even

Now the highest power of $p$ in $ac$ will be $A+C$

Now as $A+C-(A+B+B+C)=2B$ is even, so will be $A+C$

Comment: What if $b$ is zero?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, yes, it's an implicit assumption $b\ne0$

Answer (score 0):

$ab$ and $bc$ are perfect squares indicates the $ab^2c = k^2$ for some $k$.

Factoring out $b^2$ we note that $ac$ must have even powers in its prime factorization for $ab^2c$ to be a perfect square. Hence $ac$ is a perfect square.